# How to get the email_message_id for a SurveyMonkey email collector

Tags: surveymonkey

I want to use the SurveyMonkey API to trigger a SM collector to send an email directly after one of our technicians has completed his work. To this effect I am using the create_recipients API method. To send a custom message I need to provide the email_message_id. I cannot find this id. When I leave out the id SM sends the default message which is in english (I need dutch). Can anyone tell me where to find this id?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Surveymonkey Support desk; they told me that the "email_message_id" will be visible if you use the "Send_Flow" API-call. It appears that the message_id is not otherwise (easily) obtainable.

UPDATE -- 3/3/2016
Have now, in fact, created a flow in which the resulting JSON returns the e-mail message. So the way to go is to use 'send-flow' in combination with 'create_recipients'.

With many thanks to Alfred from Surveymonkey Support.

Answer (score 0):

The v2 API has no way to retrieve the email_message_id of a collector. That will be possible in v3 which should be available soon. Until then it is still possible to find the email_message_id in the HTML. Here's how to find that ID in the code for the collector, via chrome's developer tools:

- Go into the Email Collector
- Find the message under "Message History"
- Right-click on the row and select "Inspect" (Assuming you're using Chrome)
- You'll see something to the effect of `<li id="27713004">` (The ID will be unique to your message)